# Javascript-Script tag with the parent of div tag can't be executed

Tags: javascript, console

I create two tags one is `div` and another one is `script`. `Script` tag has src and it is the children to `div` tag.If I append the `div` tag to `head` or `body` of the DOM, the src of the script tag is not downloaded.
my code is

```
var scriptTag= document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
scriptTag.src = "https://example.com/example.js";
var divTag=document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML=scriptTag.outerHTML;
document.body.appenChild(divTag);
```

Note:  "https://example.com/example.js" is not an actual URL.My actual URL contains a js file.

Comment: why are you adding a script tag to a div element? Just append the script to the body

Comment: ^^ and why after doing all the work to create the element are you using `outerHTML` on it?

Comment: ... **and** note that `div` is not a valid child element of `head`.

Comment: ... **and** that `appendChild` has two `d`s in it, not just one.

Comment: I know it will work when I directly append the script tag to body.But why script tag is not executed when its child of any tags @epascarello

Comment: @VimalChandhru: It is, if you do it properly. There's no point to it, though. What do you hope to achieve by putting it in a `div`?

Comment: I want to give my customer like this div structure then why i am trying to add script to div tag @T.J.Crowder

Comment: It makes no sense for a script to be in a div in the head.... Why would you want to give your customer something like that? What is the real reason you think you need the div around the script?

Comment: @VimalChandhru: I'm afraid that sentence isn't clear. There is no difference as far as the script is concerned whether you put it in a `div` or not. (There **is** a difference if you append to `head`, since again, `div` is not a valid child for `head`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I edited my code. Please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues there:

1. `div` is not a valid child element of `head`
2. You've created a `script` element object, but then you're trying to use `outerHTML` (a round-trip through textual markup) to add it to the `div`
3. `appendChild` has two `d`s, not just one
4. There's no point to putting the script in a `div`

The correct way would be:

```
var scriptTag= document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
scriptTag.src = "https://example.com/example.js";
document.head.appendChild(scriptTag); // Or append it to document.body, doesn't matter
```

If you really, really want it in a `div`, you have to put that `div` in `body` (directly or nested):

```
var scriptTag= document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
scriptTag.src = "https://example.com/example.js";
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.appendChildD(scriptTag);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

...which will work, but is pointless.

Comment: eventhough I edited my code as like you said, It is not working